# How to implement a service layer and validation without a repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I want to build a simple Hotel Resevation System using Entity Framework adn WinForms. I've read everywhere that EF already implements the repository pattern and that DbContext is the UoW and each DbSet is a repository, thus using a RP make things a bit redundant. So how to skip it and use a service layer? What kind of operations reside in this service and where to validate objects before querying database ?
Here's how I think I should do it:

```
public class ReservationService : //(Some useful interface should be here, what do  you suggest?)
{
    public void MakeReservation(Reservation reservation)
    {
        //Validate reservation
        //Save reservation
    }
    public IEnumerable<Reservation> GetReservationsByDate(DateTime date)
    {
        //Linq queries
    }
    public IEnumerable<Reservation> GetReservationsByName(string name)
    {
        //Linq queries
    }
    public IEnumerable<Room> GetRoomsAvailable()
    {
        //Linq queries
    }
    public IEnumerable<Room> GetRoomsAvailableByDate(DateTime date)
    {

    }
}
```

**Edit:** Here's how I implemented validation:

```
public class ReservationValidator : Validator<Reservation>
{
    public ReservationValidator()
    {
        this.Errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    public override bool Validate(Reservation reservation)
    {
        if (logic here)
            this.Errors.Add("somePropertyName", "someMessage");
        if (Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks OK to me. I would move the validation to the upper layer, so if something is wrong, just tell the user that the validation failed and call the service only if everything is ok.

Comment: But what if I want to use the service in a Web ui that means I have to rewrite validation right ? Or should I make a seperate project for validation ?

Comment: Just extract the validation in separate classes. That way you can use it in different projects. Take a look at the Spring validators (just to get the idea): http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html You can write similar classes that take and object and return the validation errors.

Answer (score -1):

What if you use a generic repository pattern behind an interface you open yourself up to easily testable reusable code. Your repository implementation will expose relevant queries. When you test you can switch out the underlying data store for an in memory collection. If you rely on the dbcontext that is strongly typed to your model testing becomes a lot harder and relies on DB queries. For example

```
 public interface IRepository<T,TId>{

 T GetById(TId id);

  Etc etc

  }
```

For your dB access:

```
Public class MyConcreteDbRepos<T,TId> : IRepository<T,TId>{
      Implementation here
}
```

For your testing:

```
Public class MyInMemoryRepos<T,TId> : IRepository<T,TId>{
   Implantation here
}
```

This implentation relies on your own unit of work to hold repos of your dbsets (omitted for brevity). You don't have to do it this way if the abstraction is too heavy. You could expose the generic aspect through the methods and have one repos contain the dbcontext. You can generically select the dbset from a dbcontext.

The main point is don't rely on entity framework to do it all for you. Interfaces and design patterns help you write nicely seperated pieces of software that are easier to test and easier to maintain over the long run.

Comment: Like I said I don't want to complicate things by adding an other layer over EF, there is no need to add methods in repositories if they will have single line of code, such as the method GetById which will have something like this: context.Reservations.Find(id), for more complex queries the service layer can handle them, my question was about how to omit the repository pattern and only use a service layer and where to put validation.

Comment: Your service code says it should implement some sort of interface? I was just offering up what I've used in production. It made a massive difference when we had to add stuff later down the line. It was more testable. One of the other benefits is you can write entity specific queries using extension methods. Your validation should happen in business objects before you pass through for persistence. Your service layer serves things up so you can validate here as well if you like.